# checking for if exists/in by group across two tables

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, filtering

I have two lists of dataframes that correspond two each other for example   newdata_list$SHARKS and old_data_list$Sharks.

Within each list.dataframe  there are rows of data that can be grouped together further.

Within each new_list.dataframe and subgroups within it, I want to ensure that whichever values in my column is also present in the corresponding old_list.dataframe subgroups.

If the value in the new_list.dataframe column is not found in the corresponding table, I want to filter it out.  All combinations much match.

Here the first column is the grouping item (Animal) while the next two columns are the columns that I check to see if the value exists or not.

**I have expected answer in new_list column**

Example datasetup

```
OLD_LIST = structure(list(LAND = structure(list(Animal = structure(c(2L,  2L, 1L), .Label = c("Frogs", "Snakes"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(2L,  3L, 1L), .Label = c("Green", "Sea", "Tiger"), class = "factor"), 
    Continent = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Africa", 
    "America", "Australia"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2016L, 
    2015L, 2012L)), .Names = c("Animal", "Species", "Continent",  "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), SEA = structure(list(
    Animal = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Shark", "Whale"
    ), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Blue", 
    "Grey", "Tiger"), class = "factor"), Ocean = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Atlantic", class = "factor"), Year = c(2014L, 
    2015L, 2015L)), .Names = c("Animal", "Species", "Ocean",  "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))), .Names = c("LAND",  "SEA"))

new_list = structure(list(SEA = structure(list(Animal = structure(c(1L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Shark", "Whale"), class
= "factor"), 
    Species = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Blue", 
    "Grey", "Tiger"), class = "factor"), Ocean = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Arctic", "Atlantic", "Pacific"
    ), class = "factor"), Value = 1:5, Expected_Result = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Keep", "Remove"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Animal",  "Species", "Ocean", "Value", "Expected_Result"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), LAND = structure(list(Animal = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L), .Label = c("Frogs", "Snakes"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(3L,  3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Dart", "Hammerhead", "Tiger"), class = "factor"), 
    Continent = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Arctic", 
    "Atlantic", "Australia", "Pacific"), class = "factor"), Value = 1:5, 
    Expected_Result = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Keep", 
    "Remove"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Animal", "Species",  "Continent", "Value", "Expected_Result"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))), .Names = c("SEA", "LAND"))
```

Comment: `Snakes Tiger Australia` doesn't exist in `OLD_LIST`, so the first one comes back empty, but generally something like `library(tidyverse) ; new_list %>% sort_by(~names(.x)) %>% map2(OLD_LIST, semi_join)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work with an arbitrary number of data frame pairs:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- lst(
  new_list,
  OLD_LIST
) %>% 
  map(sort_by, names) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  map(set_names, nm = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  invoke_map(semi_join, .)
```